# How do I know if a lib is server side, client side or both?

Tags: dart

dart:html is a client side library, whereas dart:io is a server side library because this is obvious... but what about a funky lib get from http://pub.dartlang.org/packages ? Server side, client side, both ? How do I know for sure ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully the library documents whether it depends on `dart:html` or `dart:io`. If not, the only real way to know is to try it.

Comment: pub.dartlang.org should be better about categorizing packages, and/or the libraries within them, as client or server, but there are precious few developer cycles to spend on many important projects right now. One day soon hopefully.