# dart how libraries labeled for frontend or backend

Tags: dart

When I am looking at dart library, I know it for example, that dart:io works only backend. But the library dart:typed_data, it is for backend or frontend or for both.

How can I recognize, if the library is for frontend or backend? How libraries are labeled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003679/how-do-i-know-if-a-lib-is-server-side-client-side-or-both) : for the moment there is no way to make sure that a lib is client side or server side or both.